# External RFID reader on Android with JMRTD

Tags: java, android, nfc, rfid, acr122

### Context

I have a Minix x88i Android computer (not relevant, but it's **without** internal NFC tech), connected to an external RFID reader (the [ACR1252u](http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/342/acr1252u-usb-nfc-reader-iii-nfc-forum-certified-reader/) from ACS). ACS provides an [API for Android](http://android.acs.com.hk/) so I can communicate with my reader through my application. That works.

### Goal

My goal is to be able to read **ISO 14443 Type A** cards ((Dutch) ID-cards and passports (aka *ePassports*)), and get the result in my application. The key to access these tags is the MRZ (Machine Readable Zone) visible on the *ePassports*, which can be hard-coded for now.

### Problem

I'm a bit stuck on what my next step should be. I found the [JMRTD](http://jmrtd.org) API to help me access the *ePassports*, but I don't know how to use it after importing it in my application (mostly because I don't have a 'Tag' or 'Card' object or something). Applications I found using this either make use of importing `javax.smartcardio.*` or `android.nfc.*`, which both won't work in my Android application for a device without internal NFC.

Do I **need** to use JMRTD? No, if there are other libraries which do the same that I don't know about, please let me know!

You could help me by guiding me in the right direction on how to use JMRTD (or something else) for an Android application on a device without internal NFC, in combination with the ACR reader. A popular reader from them is the **ACR122**, if you have experience with that the chance is high that it will also apply for my reader! Or maybe you know of a project that does the same, so I can use that as a code example.

If I need to provide more information, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by extending the `CardService` class from SCUBA (dependecy from JMRTD) in my own class. Next I could create a `PassportService` from JMRTD, open it, select the application, perform authentication and read the data.

Comment: YOu did not need to extrend the cardservice, just use the passport service and do     passportService.doBAC(bacKey) after you have setup that passport service